# Remove node-sass from my react project which uses create-react-app

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, node-sass

I want to remove node-sass from my current react project. I want to get off sass and move to simple css format. How do I do it using npm? How to remove sass-dependency from the webpack config file which create-react-app uses internally? Overall, how to just remove everything related to sass from the project?

Comment: You sure? Sass is really great for reducing repetition and making code more organized and understandable IMO. The main problem with it is that it requires a build step, but it's already integrated into your build step :)

Comment: Yes I am sure I want to get off sass. How can I get off completely?

Comment: How do we remove the sass dependency from the webpack.config.js file and the build.js files when we use create-react-app? these files are created when we do node_modules and when we build the project

Comment: Why not just stop using it? Rename all Sass files to *.css and make sure that the content is valid CSS. I.e. Stop writing Sass files and you are done. And remove `node-sass` or `sass` package / dependency from package.json.

Comment: Yes, that is the approach I took. There is sass-loader as dependency in package-lock.json, which I won't be able to remove as it is a dependency for react-scripts, but yes, I have removed node-saas and changed all .scss files to .css files (including the syntax changes within the file).

Comment: In most cases, you should not be looking at "lock" file. If sass-loader is a dependency of react-scripts, then you can't remove this dependency in "simple" ways. And removing that dependency in "other" ways might not be a worth of time spent doing that. Both the packages are devDependencies, so no one would worry they increasing the "bundle" size. So, the best answer to your question is "don't do it". (In my opinion)

Comment: Yes sure, go ahead.

Comment: You can answer your own question @skate_23 :)

Answer (score 0):

the following steps worked for me
1.goto node modules in your project files.
2.look for node-sass folder
3.delete the node-sass folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).